# consultas cruzadas con dos OleDbDataAdapters

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010, oledb

Estoy intentando insertar registros en una tabla Access mediante un OleDbDataAdapter.

Los datos a insertar los recupero previamente de otra tabla de la misma base de datos Access con otro OleDbDataAdapter, pero cuando ejecuto el método Update del OleDbDataAdapter de destino, no inserta ningún registro.

Este es el código de creación de los DataAdapters:

```
private static OleDbDataAdapter DataAdapter()
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection con = GestionBD.Con;
            OleDbDataAdapter oleDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            string cmd = "SELECT Id, Nombre, Apellidos, Direccion, NombreCompleto, Telefono, FechaAlta, FechaBaja, FechaUltimoPedido, ImporteUltimoPedido, TotalPedidos, Observaciones FROM Clientes WHERE FechaBaja IS NOT NULL";
            oleDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(cmd, con);
            OleDbCommandBuilder cmdbuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(oleDataAdapter);

            oleDataAdapter.InsertCommand = cmdbuilder.GetInsertCommand();
            oleDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = cmdbuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
            oleDataAdapter.DeleteCommand = cmdbuilder.GetDeleteCommand();

            return oleDataAdapter;
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            throw ex2;
        }
    }

private static OleDbDataAdapter DataAdapterHistoricos()
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection con = GestionBD.Con;
            OleDbDataAdapter oleDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            string cmd = string.Empty;
            cmd = "SELECT Id, Nombre, Apellidos, Direccion, NombreCompleto, Telefono, FechaAlta, FechaBaja, FechaUltimoPedido, ImporteUltimoPedido, TotalPedidos, Observaciones FROM HistoricoClientes";                
            oleDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(cmd, con);
            OleDbCommandBuilder cmdbuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(oleDataAdapter);

            oleDataAdapter.InsertCommand = cmdbuilder.GetInsertCommand();
            oleDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = cmdbuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
            oleDataAdapter.DeleteCommand = cmdbuilder.GetDeleteCommand();

            return oleDataAdapter;
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            throw ex2;
        }
    }
```

Aquí es donde realizo la recuperación de registros y su volcado en el 2º DataAdapter:

```
DataTable c = new DataTable();

        OleDbDataAdapter da = DataAdapter();
        da.Fill(c);

        if (c.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            OleDbDataAdapter daH = DataAdapterHistoricos();
            foreach (DataRow d in c.Rows)
            {
                d.SetModified();
            }

            int cH = daH.Update(c);
```

En el foreach establezco el RowState de cada fila a Modificada porque si hago directamente el Update no me devolvia ninguna fila afectada, de este modo me devuelve el número de filas que teoricamente a actualizado/insertado, pero como ya digo no inserta ninguna fila.

Espero alguien pueda arrojar algo de luz sobre el tema, la verdad es que hace mucho que no trabajaba con Access y lo mismo estoy ignorando alguna obviedad.

Un saludo.

Comment: Si vas a insertar datos de una tabla en otra tabla dentro de la misma, te basta con hacer un insert into, y olvidarte de todo este lio...

Comment: En el resto de la aplicación uso los DataAdapter para crear y modificar registros pero es en este particular cuando me he encontrado que no consigo hacer lo que quiero, de todas formas gracias por la sugerencia.

Comment: Ok. Y donde estas pasando los datos de un da al otro?